# Не отображаются генерируемые объекты Unity

Tags: unity3d

Добрый день. Ковыряю тут урок по созданию игрушки под Android в Unity. Возникла проблема с генерируемыми объектами-"звёздами".
В иерархии видно что объекты генерируются и удаляются, когда выходят за заданные координаты. Но при этом не видно спрайтов этих объектов.[image: Звёзды]

В чём может быть ключ к решению данной проблемы?

UPD
Сам обьект "звезда"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так а почему вы спрашиваете про звёзды а показываете какой-то Generator?

Comment: А если нажать на объект звезды и посмотреть в инспекторе стоит ли у неё галочка около имени (если нету, то и не должна отображаться)

Comment: Сами звёзды идут префабами, через генератор их вывожу на поле. Галочка около имени есть и в  Sprite Renderer стоит соответствующий спрайт, но не отображается на экране.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альфа канал поставь 1, это там цвета и черная(альфа канал в нуле) полоса.

Comment: Спасибо. Затупка решена.